# Data not saved when using CreateView and ListView on same url

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the following view.py. The goal is to show CreateView form on each ListView item on same url. Now the textarea is showing, but submitting the form does not save the data. I'd really appreciate any help.

view.py:

```
class CreatePost(CreateView):
    class PostForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Post
            fields = ['post'] 
            widgets = {
            'post': forms.Textarea()
            }

class TheList(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name='item/items.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TheList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CreatePost.PostForm
        return context
```

Comment: What do you mean, on the same URL? Only one view can be called for any URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data** can't be saved automatically since `ListView` is not meant for this. You're just use its `context_data` to send a form. 
However `ListView` has `post()` and `get()` method, you can retrieve the data submitted in **post** or **get** depending on the request method.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form  = CreatePost.PostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```